# How to authomatically extract info from error messages

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am using NDSolve to compute particles' trajectories.
Typically, I get an error of the type:

NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.11880535502829011`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

What I would like is *not* to get rid of the error, but to save the time at which the simulation encountered a problem, in this case t = 0.11880535502829011`.

How can I do it in an authomatic way?

Comment: If   `U=NDSolveValue[... ]` you get the time value with `U["Domain"]`. Please provide your code.